# Error trying to build emsdk on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, build, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to follow the web assembly instructions (http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/) to install the emsdk. It all compiles fine on OSX, but I'm running into the following error when I'm trying to build it on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
[ 94%] Built target llvm-lto2
[ 94%] Built target llvm-diff
[ 94%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/llvm-c-test
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/llvm-c-test/CMakeFiles/llvm-c-test.dir/build.make:425: recipe for target 'bin/llvm-c-test' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/llvm-c-test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:15474: recipe for target 'tools/llvm-c-test/CMakeFiles/llvm-c-test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/llvm-c-test/CMakeFiles/llvm-c-test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Build failed due to exception!
Working directory: /opt/emsdk/clang/fastcomp/build_incoming_64
Command '['make', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Installation failed!
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the main problem when building emsdk is swapping, because it looks like the installation script detect 4 logical processor cores and starts 3-threaded compilation. And when everything is compiled, several linker processes (`ld`) appears to be launched simultaneously and they exhaust my 8 Gb of RAM (at least when Firefox with many tabs is running at the same time). The system becomes unresponsive and I have to either stop using it and wait or terminate one of `ld` processes, then in my case other two will finish linking and although installation will fail, when I rerun it, there are 2 less binaries to link :).

I have tried to simulate memory exhaustion without swap with

```
$ ulimit -v 2000000
$ ./emsdk install sdk-incoming-64bit
```

And got the same error `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` but with something like `/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: Memory exhausted` just before it.

I'm completely unsure you have precisely this problem (especially because you don't have any `Memory exhausted` message and you are performing single-threaded compilation (`make -j1`)), but there may probably be other failure scenarios in `ld` when memory is exhausted. You can rerun installation while observing the `top` output on the other terminal examining whether free memory **+ buff/cache** goes to almost 0 (**just** free mem at almost 0 may be fine). If so, you can try to use swap partition or file. Unfortunately, you cannot use the trick with terminating one of `ld` processes, because you already have just single-threaded compilation (`make -j1`).

Comment: Thanks! That is a thorough explanation! :) I was also able to fix this by asking help directly to the web assembly guys: https://github.com/WebAssembly/website/issues/103